# High performance Solr Tag Cloud

Tags: solr

I am looking at how to implement a high performance tag cloud in Solr.

I have a Solr database with 15 million records and more added every day.  I have a field in which several copy statements copy data into.  It can have anywhere between 1 and 6 values.  These values are usually a sentence or two (string data).  I've attempted to create a custom field type to optimize & tokenize the field for quick faceting but I'm getting lackluster performance.

Here is the custom field that I've created.

```
    <fieldType name="KeywordCloud" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve at least reasonable performance when faceting this field?  Or is there a totally different approach that I can take?

This approach works great when I only have an index of a million documents or so, but 15 million and higher is giving me issues.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you play with the solr cache? As the number of unique terms for a field gets bigger, you need to grow the cache accordingly. See [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching) for details. Pay attention on the filter cache and on the field cache.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Is there any defined recommendations that I can follow?  Would be great if there was some math I could apply to figure out the optimal configuration.

Comment: Not really math, but you can monitor the cache statistics while you are doing requests on your index (look for the "Statistics" > "Cache" link from the Solr Admin console). If you see many evictions, your cache size are probably too low. But don't go too high as this could hurt your system too.